# making file name lower case while preserving extension

Tags: php

Suppose I have the following piece of code:

```
  $myString = 'FilE.EXE';

  strlower($myString);
```

I want to make the name minus its extension to lower case, but the code above will make the entire string into lower case. Is there a way I can just change the name without the extension? If so, what is the most dynamic way to accomplish this?

Desired output: 'file.EXE';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

`$myString = 'FilE.EXE';
$new_string = strtolower(pathinfo($myString, PATHINFO_FILENAME)) . '.' . pathinfo($myString,  PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
echo $new_string;`

Answer (score 2):

You need to do something like this:

```
$string = "FilE.EXE";
list($name, $extension) = explode('.', $string);
$string = implode('.', array(strtolower($name), $extension));
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

do:

```
$myString = 'FilE.EXE';
$txt = strtolower( substr( $myString, 0, strrpos($myString, ".") ) )
          .substr( $myString, strrpos($myString, "."),  strlen($myString));
echo $txt; //gives file.EXE
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) function for that:

```
$myString = 'FilE.iNc.EXE';

$path_parts = pathinfo($myString);

$myNewString = implode('.', array(
    strtolower($path_parts['filename']),
    $path_parts['extension']
));
```

So it can ouput this:

```
file.inc.EXE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$myString = 'FilE.EXE';
$txt = strtolower( substr( $myString, 0, strrpos($myString, ".") ) );
$hell  = substr( $myString, strrpos($myString, "."),  strlen($myString));
$babe = $txt.$hell;
echo $babe;
```